# How many people have been called Captain America in the mainstream Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, falcon

In the canon Marvel Universe (Earth-616) Steve Rogers (Captain America) has lost his super-soldier serum and has passed the mantle of Captain America to Sam Wilson (the Falcon).

There is great debate about the other characters who have been Captain America when Steve Rogers was either dead or incapacitated.

**Can anyone tell me who those characters are and what years their run in the comics took place?** I am looking for a definitive list of these individuals complete with costumes (if possible).

Note: While the site abhors list questions, I know this is a finite list of less than ten individuals.

Comment: This is exactly the type of question I thought you would have been the one to answer first.

Comment: Unfortunately, my new job precludes having time for much research. So now I am counting on someone else to save the day for me.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_incarnations_of_Captain_America

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Captain_America

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TL;DR - 9 people have been called Captain America to-date**

This information has been summarized from the excellent article on [comicvine](http://www.comicvine.com/captain-america/4005-1442/).

- **Steve Rogers** - the original and the person who spends the most time as Captain America. Steve has primarily used two versions of the uniform.

[image: The original uniform]

[image: The classic uniform]

- **Isaiah Bradley** - another test subject for the super-soldier serum. He acts as a super-soldier after Steve was lost. He steals Steve's extra suit and shield and uses it on one mission and is then arrested and court martialed for doing so. It should be noted that he was never officially titled as Captain America, but was considered to be "the Black Captain America" by reputation.

[image: Isaiah Bradley as Cap.]

- **The Spirit  of '76 (William Nasland)** - becomes the first published replacement as Captain America. He is killed by Adam II in 1946. Nasland wears the classic uniform.

[image: William Nasland]

- **The Patriot (Jeff Mace)** - becomes the next Captain America. After his Bucky is replaced by Golden Girl, he eventually quits and marries Golden Girl. Mace wears the classic uniform.

[image: Jeff Mace]

- In 1953 **William Burnside** finds the super-soldier serum and undergoes plastic surgery to look like Steve Rogers, but the project is cancelled and he becomes a teacher. He later meets Jack Monroe and the two use the serum to become Captain America and Bucky respectively. However, due to not using the Vita-Ray process in conjunction with the serum, they go insane. The government shuts them down and places them in suspended animation. Burnside wears the classic uniform.

[image: William Burnside]

- Namor finds the Inuits worshiping a figure in a block of ice and throws the block into the ocean, where the Avengers find and rescue Steve Rogers. Steve returns as Captain America. Rick Jones becomes the new Bucky. Steve wears the classic uniform.
- After the Watergate scandal, Steve Rogers becomes *Nomad* and **Roscoe Simons** becomes Captain America. Simons is eventually killed by the Red Skull and Steve returns. Simons wears the classic uniform.

[image: Roscoe Simons]

- Steve begins resigning as Captain America when the US Government starts forcing him to work solely for them. **John Walker** becomes the stand-in Captain America when Steve refuses. Walker eventually becomes *US Agent* and Steve returns as Captain America full-time. Walker wears the classic uniform.

[image: John Walker]

- During the *Sentinel of Liberty* storyline, Steve is briefly presumed dead during issues 8 and 9, **The Falcon (Sam Wilson)** takes over as Captain America for one issue (#9). Sam wears the classic uniform.

[image: Sam Wilson - standing in as Cap]

- After Steve is apparently assassinated following the Civil War, Tony Stark follows Steve's instructions in a letter and finds and saves **Bucky Barnes**. Bucky becomes Captain America and remains as such even after Steve returns to the present time. Bucky is the first new Captain to wear a significantly redesigned uniform.

[image: Finally. A new uniform!]

- After Bucky is apparently killed, Steve Rogers becomes Captain America again.
- When the Super Soldier serum in Steve Rogers is neutralized, Steve rapidly begins aging. He appoints Sam Wilson as the new Captain America. Instead of just wearing Steve's old uniform again, he wears an updated version of the classic design with Falcon's wings integrated.

[image: Cap + Falcon]

Comment: Getting this up here for now. I'll try to edit in costumes and whatever more specific dates that I can find.

Comment: I could have sworn Sam Wilson has assumed the Captain title once before too.  I'll check my back issues this afternoon when I get home.

Comment: @Monty129 I keep finding references to Sam being Cap's partner or role as leader, but I can't find any instance of him taking on the actual identity.

Comment: @Monty129 OK, I found it. Editing the answer.

Comment: Found it, in **Captain America: Sentinel of Liberty** #8-9 he assumed the title for one issue (#9 specifically).

Comment: Was William Burnside the guy who became Nuke?

Comment: @krillgar, No, he was brainwashed into *The Grand Director* at one point, but *Nuke* was a completely separate character.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuke_(Marvel_Comics)#cite_note-24

Comment: Then he (Nuke) has also posed as Captain America. Not as official hero, but dressed up and was smearing Captain America as him. It was within the last couple years, but I don't have anything in front of me right now.

Comment: @Richard that citation is for *Ultimate Comics: Captain America #2*, which exists in Earth-1610. The question is specifically about Earth-616.

Comment: @krillgar That's Earth-1610 - the Ultimate Universe. The question specifically asks for information regarding Earth-616.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been addressed to @Krillgar

Comment: You're right. I deleted that comment. I didn't notice that part. I don't read the Ultimate Universe, but I do still remember him pretending to be Cap within the last couple of years. I didn't see anything on the 616 article, so I'll try to look it up this weekend. Until then, I'll back off my assertion as supposition for the time being.

Comment: @krillgar It's all good. If anyone can find a good reference, I'll be happy to add it in.

Comment: I may be imagining things here, but didn't Crossbones wear the outfit at one point to frame Cap for something or other? That doesn't really fall into the "assumed the mantle" nature of the question but might be fun to include as trivia.

Comment: @Omegacron I haven't been able to find anything mentioning it, but it's certainly possible. The closest I've found so far is Cap disguising himself as Crossbones.