# How many characters have taken on the mantle of Captain America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

We think of Steve Rogers as the only Captain America because of the modern Captain America and Avengers movies. But in  [the Captain America serial films of the 1940s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America_(serial)) his alter-ego was a district attorney named Grant Gardner.

[image]

No doubt, the Captain America story has had numerous re-imaginings over the years, so how many different characters have worn the Red, White and Blue of Captain America?

Was it just Grant Gardner and Steve Rogers or have there been any others?

[image]

Comment: Several characters have taken up the mantle of Captain America in the comics. Are we counting them or just film/TV roles?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_incarnations_of_Captain_America :)    Plus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Captain_America

Comment: Related: [How many people have been called Captain America in the mainstream Marvel Universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63488/5184)

Comment: “We think of Steve Rogers as the only Captain America because of the modern Captain America and Avengers movies” — maybe *you* do! [Peter Fonda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Rider) all the way to Mardi Gras, man.

Comment: Also do we think Grant Gardner was Guy Gardner’s brother?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been many Captain Americas throughout the years.

[image]

Here's a list of Cap's from the regular **comic** Marvel Universe (that is to say that these are The Canonical Captains) in the order they held the Captian America mantle, not the order they were created:

- [Steve Rogers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America) -1st Appearance: 1941 Captain America Comics #1
- [Isaiah Bradley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Bradley) -1st Appearance: 2003 Truth: Red, White & Black #1
- [William Nasland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_of_%2776_(Marvel_Comics)) -1st Appearance: 1977 Invaders #14
- [Jeffrey Mace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Mace) -1st Appearance: 1940 Human Torch Comics #3
- [William Burnside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Director) -1st Appearance: 1972 (retconned to 1953) Captain America #153
- [Bob Russo](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_178) -1st Appearance: 1974 Captain America #178
- [Scar Turpin](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_179) -1st Appearance: 1974 Captain America #179
- [Roscoe Simons](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_181) -1st Appearance: 1975 Captain America #181
- [John Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Agent) -1st Appearance: 1986 Captain America #323
- [Sam Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(comics)) -1st Appearance: 1969 Captain America #117 (though events here only retconned in the 1999 Sentinel of Liberty series)
- [James Buchanan Barnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucky) -1st Appearance: 1941 Captain America Comics #1 (as Cap in 2008 Captain America vol 5 #34)
- [Dave Rickford](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_615.1) -1st Appearance: 2011 Captain America #615.1
- [Sam Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(comics)) (Sam takes over again in 2014 Captain America vol 7 #25)

For most of these characters things did not turn out too well.

[image]

There are also a slue of Alternate Versions of Cap throughout time and the multiverse. Some are characters we know like Scott Summers (AKA Cyclops), while others are somewhat similar like Samantha Wilson from Earth-65 (Where Spider-[Gwen]-Woman comes from). You can see a list of them here: [Alt-Vers Caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Captain_America)

In Films and Television however [Grant Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America_(serial)) was the only OTHER person, aside from Steve Rogers, revealed to be Captain America.

[image]

Comment: “Captains America”, surely.